# Remove symbols from string but keep whitespaces

Tags: python

I need to remove special characters from a string but I also need to keep whitespaces. This is my code so far:

```
from unidecode import unidecode
import re

def cleanstr(string):
    if isinstance(string, str):
        string = string.decode('utf-8')
    string = unidecode(string)
    string = re.sub('[^A-Za-z0-9]+', '', string)
    return string

print cleanstr("She's my friend Adélaïde")
>> ShesmyfriendAdelaide
```

The expected result should be `Shes my friend Adelaide`.

Comment: So modify the regular expression to keep whitespaces. What am I missing?

Comment: @omri_saadon How?

Comment: what are "special characters" exactly? once you've defined that it's fairly trivial to remove them by regex or without

Comment: @omri_saadon I don't think that's the change that was being suggested. (Hint: add a space to the character class.)

Comment: You do not only need to remove special characters, you need to transform some as well. Like `ï` to `i`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Without regular expressions

```
import string

sentence = "vg583$%#jgv f_vrefg fh4ufrh4 %# dhejrfh #"

print "".join([s for s in sentence if s in string.ascii_letters + string.digits + ' '])
```

Output

```
'vg583jgv fvrefg fh4ufrh4  dhejrfh'
```

I admit, can not handle unicode at the moment but you may need to tweak it a bit.

I think your final solution (in case you do want to deal with unicode) should look like this:

```
u''.join([transform_char(c) for c in your_unicode_string if condition_met(c)])
```

Comment: Why giving me a -1?

Comment: The question clearly shows that the input string is UTF-8.

Answer (score 1):

```
[^A-Za-z0-9]+
```

Here you're matching characters that are not A-Z, a-z or 0-9.

You replace these characters with the empty string; that is, you remove them.

If you want to remove other characters, then simply add them to this list!
`\s` means whitespace, so:

```
[^A-Za-z0-9\s]+
```